# How can I write the length of a list to a txt file?

Tags: python

Ideally I would write:

```
file.write("You have", len(gen1), "customers in 'Generation Z'.")
```

but it won't accept that with 3 arguments

Comment: turn those 3 "things" into one string using `+`. Note that you'd have to convert len to a string.

Comment: `print("You have", len(gen1), "customers", file=file)` would also work.

Comment: you could also call `file.write()` 3 times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass it as a single string, instead of individual arguments as you have in your example.

You could do this:

```
file.write("You have" + str(len(gen1)) + "customers in 'Generation Z'.")
```

or this:

```
file.write ("You have {} customers in 'Generation Z'.".format(len(gen1)))
```

or even:

```
file.write ("You have %s customers in 'Generation Z'." % len(gen1))
```

Not that for concatenation (first option), you'll have to explicitly convert `len(gen1)` to a string using `str()` while it's a bit cleaner using the `.format` or `%` notation.

Comment: For completion, [the documentation for the `.write()` method of text files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write). Note that it only gets one parameter.